# "A matching symbol file was not found in this folder " . Getting this error when i try to debug using dump file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, dump

We are having some issue in customer site. So we generated the dump in their site.
Now to find out the issue we are loading the dump file from visual studio.
I had given the correct symbol path also.

[Error which i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8c13.png)

[A matching symbol file was not found in this folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXDFb.png)

[Error msg (Eventhough pdb is present is same loaction )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QATZA.png)

Even though the pdb is present it is saying  "A matching symbol file was not found in this folder "

Should the time stamp and date should be same for dll and pdb ? ( In my case pdb and dll source code is same , but date which both are built are different )

In my visual studio in options i have disabled the source code must be same check box also.

My source code is in c++.

Is the time stamp mismatch is the issue  ?
Is so any workaround is there for this ?

Or any thing which i am doing wrongly ?

I tried to debug using both Visual studio 2013 and Visual studio 2019

Thank you for your time....

Comment: Not the timestamp, but that does indicate some mismatch. You could try to use WinDbg instead. [Per MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format?view=vs-2019): "*The name and signature in the PDB file must match the executable for symbols to be loaded in the debugger. The WinDBG debugger can load mismatched symbols by using the* ***.symopt+0x40*** *command. Visual Studio doesn't have a similar option to load mismatched symbols.*".

Comment: @dxiv I used the windbg . And i used the command .symopt+0x40. But i am getting "*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for opldcm.dll " , could u plz help me out . Thanks

Comment: And Source code for pdb and dll are same for sure

Comment: That's just a warning, which you can ignore. As long as the symbols are close enough, WinDbg does a good job at using them. About the code being the same, that's not (always) enough. The only guaranteed match is when both the .dll and the .pdb are produced in the same build by the same link invocation.

Comment: Thank you. There was a signature mismatch b/w my dll and pdb .I used Chkmatch tool to check , and i corrected the pdb using the same tool .And it worked . Thank you so much for your help (Link for the tool "http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html" )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you.
There was a signature mismatch b/w my dll and pdb .I used Chkmatch tool to check , and i corrected the pdb using the same tool .And it worked .

Link for the tool http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html

Commands :
chkmatch -c ExeFile/dll DebugInfoFile(pdb)
--> This command will tell whether your pdb and dll matches

chkmatch -m ExeFile/dll DebugInfoFile(pdb)
--> This command will correct your pdb. So this pdb can be used for debugging purpose.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: For others debugging a dump/minidump: To prevent a simple version mismatch, have a look into the _Modules_ section at the _Module Version_ to find the needed pdb version.